# imported function can't find configuration file

Tags: python, import, configuration

I have some python files, that uses a configuration file called `credentials.json`

whenever my file is in the same folder as the `credentials.json` file it works fine, but when the function is imported I get the following error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'`.

I linked a picture of my file structure from my folder
[image]

I have a `configuration.py` file, where I have a hardcoded value for my credentials.json file.

But as pointed out in the answers I think the path needs to be relative
how can I make the path work even when the function is imported?

Comment: why the dislike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show any code, but I bet that you have '`credentials.json'` hardcoded in the function's body. The solution is either change it to the absolute path, or even better, pass the path to `credentials.json` as an argument.

Comment: I tried with the absolute path, and that did not work properly